# Calling vs invoking a function

Tags: javascript

Up to this point, I thought "calling" and "invoking" a function meant the same thing. However, in a YouTube tutorial it said to invoke a function *by calling it*. My first thought was that the wording was a mistake, but on W3Schools' [page](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_invocation.asp) on Function Invocation, it says:

> It is common to use the term "call a function" instead of "invoke a
>   function" ... In this tutorial, we will use invoke, because a
>   JavaScript function can be invoked without being called.

Okay, so there's a difference. What is it?

Comment: Seems like quite a gray area, but "invoke" suggests some degree of indirection. So you might consider instantiation via `new` (e.g. `new MyThing()`) to be an invocation rather than a call. The use of `.call` or `.apply` could also be considered an invocation rather than a call. But W3Schools' insistence on using "invoke" everywhere seems very unnatural to me.

Comment: "because a JavaScript function can be invoked without being called"... would love an explanation of this... Best thing I ever did was get an extension that blocks W3Schools.

Comment: I wonder if w3schools it all relevant anymore - I remember linking to a w3schools page in one of my first answers here - the reception was cold

Comment: IMO, that's a misleading statement. Maybe there are some indication of call/apply or something else but it's totally confusing.

Comment: @Jordan S You are wise.

Comment: `fn()` "invoke" (without call) vs `fn.call()` with the use of "call";

Comment: See also 7907067
18505422

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Your reference text:

> It is common to use the term "call a function" instead of "invoke a
>   function" ... In this tutorial, we will use invoke, because a
>   JavaScript function can be invoked without being called.

Now let me rephrase it:

> It is common to use the term "call a function" instead of "invoke a
>   function" ... In this tutorial, we will use the term **invoke** instead of **call**, because a
>   JavaScript function can be invoked **indirectly** like `fn.call()` and `fn.apply()` without being called **directly** like `fn()`.

So, when I do `fn()`, it's invoked directly and when I do it like `fn.call()`, it's invoked indirectly but in both cases, the function is being invoked. Otherwise, I see no difference here and I can also say that I can call a function in many ways, for example:

```
fn(); // I'm calling it
fn.call(); // I'm calling it
fn.apply(); // I'm calling it
```

So, the difference is semantic but both are interchangeable, IMO. BTW, I wrote a comment above, under the question and I would like to put it here, which is:

> IMO, that's a misleading statement. Maybe there are some indication of
>   call/apply or something else but it's totally confusing.

Comment: So just to be sure, you're saying whenever a function is invoked, it's also being called, and it's accurate to say that "calling" is interchangeable with "invoking" (even given the distinction that it can be either a direct or indirect call/invocation)?

Comment: Yup! I think so :-)

Comment: I think invoking a  function describes how the function is bound to the function call(static binding or dynamic binding). So when we say `function ()`  we are actually calling it. But depending upon the use case , the function is "invoked"  (or bound )dynamically or static-ally

Answer (score 29):

The difference is semantic and subtle. When you call a function, you are directly telling it to run. When you invoke a function, you are letting something run it.

There is one way to call a function:

```
myFunction()
```

Here, you are invoking the function (letting it run) by calling it directly.

There are many ways to invoke a function (given throughout different comments and answers). Here's one example:

```
function invoker(functionName) {
  functionName() 
}

invoker(myFunction)
```

Here, by calling `invoker`, you are invoking `myFunction`, which is being called indirectly.

Comment: invoker is still calling functionName.   This is a bit misleading.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, in most cases we use both to refer the execution of a function.

> There are 2 ways to reach place **B** from your **HOME**.
>
> 1. Direct/Automatic way (Invoke), i.e. if you choose first way, you do not need to walk. Someone will automatically take you to place **B**.
> 2. Indirect way (Call), i.e. if choose second way, you only need to reach **A**(by walk). Someone is there at place **A** to automatically take you to place **B**.

Have a look at the below image. I think it will clear your doubt.

[image]

In case of **Calling**, you originally refer to the statement that actually calls the function.

In case of **Invoking**, you indirectly refer to calling statement to actually invoke/run the function.

Answer (score 3):

Many people use the term calling and invoking interchangeably but that's not right. There is a very slight difference between calling and invoking a function. In JavaScript functions can be invoked without being called which means that the code inside the body of the function can be executed without creating an `object` for the same. It is tied to the global object. When there is no individual object, the value of `this` is associated with the global object.

There is also a difference between `call` and `apply`, the fundamental difference is that call() accepts an argument list, while apply() accepts a single array of arguments. A different `this` object can be assigned when calling an existing function. `this` refers to the current object, the calling object. With `call`, you can write a method once and then inherit it in another object, without having to rewrite the method for the new object.

So, the major difference between invoking and calling comes in terms of the `this` object. Calling let's you set the `this` value whereas invoking just ties it to the global object.

Answer (score -2):

"function invoked" means a function got executed

"function called" means that a function was called by another function and then executed

"function invoked without being called" is a function that got self invoked without being called by another function

```
example of a self invoking function calling another function:
var f = (function() { 
   foo();
})();  ///() here means it self invoked -- without being called directly.

var foo = (function() {
    ///Do something here
});
```

Comment: "function called" means that a function was called by another function and then executed - where are you getting this distinction?

Comment: I'm not sure I entirely understand the question. Function being called by another function means specifically that...

Comment: I just added to the example above. -- The Self calling function -- calls the function foo
Notice that nothing called the function f

Comment: But you can call a function without another function calling it.