# Is there a difference between calling and invoking a function?

Tags: javascript

I am getting trouble to implement the instruction below

```
At this point, letsCalculateBMI is ready to claculate the user's BMI. It should do this by calling computeBMI and passing it user. 

It then sets the return value from invoking computeBMI to a bmi variable, which is finally set as the text content of the PARAGRAPH within the #outcome DIV
```

I tried different possibilities but the test runner can't pass although the result returned by the app is correct.

I am building an app and this is the last user story. This is what I tried:

```
const computeBMI = ({weight, height, country}) => {

        const convertedHeight = height * 0.3048;
        let bmi = (weight / convertedHeight * convertedHeight);

        if (healthiestCountries.includes(country)) bmi *= 0.82;

        //document.querySelector('#outcome p').innerHTML = bmi;

        return bmi;        
        };

      const letsCalculateBMI = () => {
        const value = document.querySelector('.select-text').value;
        const user = getSelectedUser(value);
        //computeBMI(user);
        const bmi = computeBMI(user);

        document.querySelector('#outcome p').innerHTML = bmi;
        console.log(user)
      };
```

From the instruction above, do you thing that my implementation misses something? What is the difference between call and invoke a function?

Comment: IMO the difference between the two words is so that whoever wrote that instruction was trying to avoid repeating themselves

Comment: I kinda agree with James. You can "call" or "apply" functions like the examples in this ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50884893/calling-vs-invoking-a-function/50885071 ) question, but in this case it's just a matter of wording imho

Comment: If that's so, why am I getting error when I do this:
computeBMI(user) in stead of cont bmi = computeBMI(user)?

Comment: what error? `computeBMI(user)` is still calling/invoking the function in the same way whether you make use of the return value or not.  Is it just that if you drop the `const bmi` bit, that variable isn't there to set the `innerHTML` on the following line?

Comment: Following the instruction aboveIf letsCalculateBMI() calls computerBMI() and passes user to it, then after it takes the returned value from that function and assign it to bmi var. So if I do like this
computerBMI(user); // first instruction
const bmi = computerBMI(); // second one
I get this error "Paused on exception
TypeError: (destructured parameter) is undefined". That's why I am wondering if call differs from invoke.

Comment: in that situation, you're calling (or invoking - they're the same) it twice. The first time with the `user` parameter, the second time without.

Comment: So, what would be the solution to comply with the instruction above?

Comment: Even though I comment const bmi I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Is there someone to help with my question?